# Java: Runtime.getRuntime().exec is not working

Tags: java, visual-studio, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am writing a Java application that gets a command (as String) and runs it:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = in.nextLine();
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + command);
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

I try to run it with this command: `start devenv.exe` but I get a message from Windows that "This app can't run on your PC" :

[image]

If I try to run `start winword.exe` - Word is opened.

If I export the application and run the jar itself with the same command - Visual Studio is opened.

The same application on another computer - works well.

Do  you have any idea if the problem is with Visual Studio, the Eclipse, or something on the specific computer?

Thanks!

Comment: Is Eclipse / the java process running under the same user as that which runs 'start devenv.exe'. Also, does it work from a simple java class 'main' method?

Comment: My guess is that it is something to do with environment variables and/or 32 versus 64 bit.

Comment: @Stephen: All of the computers and the apps are 64 bit, so I assume that this is not the problem :(

Comment: @user5699936 - But is Eclipse itself 64 bit?  If Eclipse is 32 bit, then it could be passing this on to the child process in the form of an environment variable that is setting a library / dll path for 32 bit dlls.  Possibly.

Comment: @Stephen C - The Eclipse is 64 bit, too.